# How does pySerial implement the "with" statement without __enter__ and __exit__?

Tags: python, pyserial, contextmanager

pySerial can be used with Python's `with` statement like this:

```
with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS1") as ser:
    ser.write("AAAA")
    ser.read(8)
```

I tried to see exactly what it is pySerial does to make this work, but I couldn't find an `__enter__` or `__exit__` function anywhere! I ran `grep -e '\(__enter__\)\|\(__exit__\)' *.py` from the pySerial directory, and grep didn't find either function. How does pySerial do it?

**Edit:** I also tried the following to see what was called next:

```
import serial, pdb
with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0") as ser:
    pdb.set_trace()
```

This brought me directly to line 433 of `serialposix.py`, the `close()` function. Does the `with` statement also look for `open()` and `close()` functions?

Comment: Wild guess: it uses the [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serial` class doesn't implement these methods, it inherits them from [`io.IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io.rawiobase#io.IOBase). The relevant part from [/serial/serialposix.py](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/pyserial/code/trunk/pyserial/serial/serialposix.py):

```
try:
    import io
except ImportError:
    # classic version with our own file-like emulation
    class Serial(PosixSerial, FileLike):
        pass
else:
    # io library present
    class Serial(PosixSerial, io.RawIOBase):
        pass
```